# Update a una tabla , error Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, update

No entiendo muy bien donde puedo decirle a mi función Update que use mi idProyectos, en vez de la id que usa por defecto (id). Me extraña mucho que no funcione si al mostrar información o traerla en el formulario update funciona perfectamente considerando idProyectos, buscando el mismo error en este sitio y en google mencionan que hay que asignar como "primaryKey" el id que quiero usar = idProyectos, pero no lo identifica.

mi tabla contiene:

> idproyecto (AI unique), proyectoNombre (varchar 255),proyectoDescripcion (varchar 255)

mi modelo es:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Proyecto extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'idProyectos';
    protected $fillable = ['proyectoNombre', 'proyectoDescripcion'];
}
```

mi vista:

```
  <form method="post" action="{{ route('proyectosUpdate', $proyecto->idProyectos) }}">
    <div class="form-group">        
          @csrf
          @method('PATCH')
          <label for="name">proyectoNombre:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="proyectoNombre" value="{{$proyecto->proyectoNombre}}"/>
    </div>   
    <div class="form-group">  
          <label for="name">proyectoDescripcion:</label>  
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="proyectoDescripcion" value="{{$proyecto->proyectoDescripcion}}"/>
    </div>       
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>
  </form>
```

mi ruta :

```
Route::PATCH('/proyectosUpdate/{idProyectos}', 'HomeController@proyectosUpdate')->name('proyectosUpdate');
```

mi funcion dentro de mi controlador:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Proyecto;
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function proyectosUpdate(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'proyectoNombre' => 'required|max:255',
            'proyectoDescripcion' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);
        Proyecto::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);
        return redirect('/proyectos');
    }
```

mi error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `proyectos` set `proyectoNombre` = Proyecto 1, `proyectoDescripcion` = Descripción del proyecto 1, `proyectos`.`updated_at` = 2019-05-13 16:38:47 where `id` = 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú mismo le estás diciendo que busque el campo id en la base de datos, al momento de realizar la consulta con eloquent:

```
    Proyecto::whereId($id)->update($validatedData);
```

Tal vez debas usar el nombre de campo correcto:

```
    Proyecto::where('idProyectos', $id)->update($validatedData);
```

Comment: muchas gracias, es el whereId a where como tu dices, es horrible ser nuevo en esto muchas gracias esa era la solucion :.)

Comment: si xD es que solo me deja poner la aceptacion de respuesta asta dentro de 6 minutos jejej respondiste muy rapido :D gracias otra ves